# SQL cohort query output

Tags: sql

This is a sample query and I do not have the data associated with these values, but I just need to know what kind of chart/information would be the output of this request:

```
SELECT 
 cohorts.cohortyear, 
 YEAR(orders.time) AS purchaseyear, 
 SUM(orders.amount) AS amount 

FROM orders, 
(SELECT id AS customer_id, YEAR(created) AS cohortyear FROM customers) AS cohorts 
WHERE orders.customer_id = cohorts.customer_id
GROUP BY cohortyear, purchaseyear;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query would be better written and more intelligible if it used explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT co.cohortyear, YEAR(o.time) AS purchaseyear, SUM(o.amount) AS amount 
FROM orders o join
     (SELECT id AS customer_id, YEAR(created) AS cohortyear
      FROM customers cu
     ) co 
     on o.customer_id = co.customer_id
GROUP BY co.cohortyear, purchaseyear;
```

It is taking customers and assigning them to similarity groups based on the year the `customers` record was created (assuming `created` does what it sounds like).  So, all customers created in the same year are in the same group.   Then, it calculates the amount spent in each year on or after that one.  If you ran the query, the output would be pretty self explanatory.  Something like:

```
CohortYear   PurchaseYear     Amount
  2014           2014         $1000
  2013           2014         $2000
  2013           2013         $3000
  . . .
```

The first row says that for customers who started in 2014, they spent $1000 in 2014.  By contrast, customers who start in 2013 spent $2000 in 2014.  And this group spent $3000 in 2013.  However, the comparisons aren't very good, because it doesn't take into account the number of customers.  But that is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question. By looking at the projections in the `SELECT` clause I am going to guess your output columns will look like:

`cohortyear (integer) | purchaseyear (integer) | amount (some numeric)`

Comment: The scenario is that I was sent this query and need to understand the information (insights) this would show and why it is valuable. This helps!